# Linux Bash Script Awk Field Separator

Tags: bash, awk

I have a data below:

```
Mike Harrington:(510) 548-1278:250:100:175
Christian Dobbins:(408) 538-2358:155:90:201
Susan Dalsass:(206) 654-6279:250:60:50 
Archie McNichol:(206) 548-1348:250:100:175 
Jody Savage:(206) 548-1278:15:188:150 
Guy Quigley:(916) 343-6410:250:100:175 
Dan Savage:(406) 298-7744:450:300:275 
Nancy McNeil:(206) 548-1278:250:80:75 
John Goldenrod:(916) 348-4278:250:100:175 
Chet Main:(510) 548-5258:50:95:135 
Tom Savage:(408) 926-3456:250:168:200 
Elizabeth Stachelin:(916) 440-1763:175:75:300
```

I'm trying to use awk to print out all of the phone numbers. I found 2 way to do it:

```
1/ awk '{print substr($2, length($2)-4, length($2)), substr($3,1,8)}' awk.data 
2/ awk -F[:] '{print $2}' awk.data
```

It both return the same result. I understand how my first-way work but I don't understand the second one. I know it is using field separator but I don't understand how it works. Can someone help me to explain, please?

Comment: You can also use `cut -d: -f2 awk.data`, btw.

Comment: check out the [Awk Tutorial](https://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) . `-F[:]` and `FS=":"` are equivalent. Good luck.

Comment: The value passed to -F or FS is seen as a string and then is converted to regexp.

- You can see it in "4.5 Specifying How Fields Are Separated": https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Field-Separators.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's pick the first record in your data file:

```
Mike Harrington:(510) 548-1278:250:100:175
```

The `awk` argument `-F:` makes `:` a field separator as you've figured out. What happens is that the special `awk` variables (with the prefix `$`) numbered from `1` and up are assigned the value of the fields:

```
Mike Harrington            $1
(510) 548-1278             $2
250                        $3
100                        $4
175                        $5
```

That is, every `:` encountered makes `awk` assign what follows to one of these special variables.